# Enviar arquivo para outro servidor usando Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um Sistema Web que vou passar para uma hospedagem. Mais tenho o sistema com 2 bancos (um para o site e o outro está na minha casa para path dos arquivos, documentos, logs, etc), o script ficará na hospedagem e os path dos arquivos no servidor na minha casa. O problema e o seguinte, por questões de segurança e consumo de espaço não posso enviar estes arquivos para a hospedagem.
Então o usuário vai enviar o documento pelo formulário, o PHP se conecta com o banco na minha casa e grava os dados do documento e envia o arquivo para minha casa.

Como posso fazer isso?

Estive pensando em enviar via requisição Ajax pro meu servidor local e passando o retorno para validação de erros. O que acham?

Comment: Só uma coisa. Se você acha que os arquivos estão mais seguros na sua casa, você tem muito o que aprender sobre segurança. Um serviço de hospedagem vai ter toda uma equipe profissional cuidando da segurança da rede deles, enquanto que no seu PC pessoal basta você cometer um deslize que você está lascado. E por deslize digo contrair um vírus que faça algo sacana como o WannaCry, deixar o diretório raiz compartilhado na rede por engano etc. Fora que se o seu PC quebrar, já era. Na hospedagem você vai ter no mínimo replicação na nuvem com backups diários.

Comment: Opa amigo, sim. No momento do desenvolvimento estou fazendo assim antes de colocar em produção. Mais onde vou implementar tem um server com backup 4 vezes ao dia. A hospedagem e somente para manter o site de noticias e serviços rodando. Como em torno de 3000  documentos por ano não tem como ficar na hospedagem.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema com a `class FTP` do `codeigniter` que e o framework que estou utilizando.
Configurei a segunda conexão do banco para minha casa e logo após fazer a inserção, edição ou excluir os dados, o php salva o arquivo na hospedagem em uma pasta temporaria e executo o seguinte script:

```
      $caminho_temp= "Arquivos/TEMP/DE/{$this->input->post('numero')}_{$this->input->post('ano')}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";

      $source = $caminho_temp;
        $this->load->library('ftp');
        //FTP configuration
        $ftp_config['hostname'] = '###.150.##.123';
        $ftp_config['username'] = '@@@@@@';
        $ftp_config['password'] = '@@@@@@';
        $ftp_config['debug']    = FALSE;

        //Connect to the remote server
        if($this->ftp->connect($ftp_config) == TRUE){

          //File upload path of remote server
          $destino = "/Arquivos/DE/{$fileName}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";
          $destino_url = "Arquivos/DE/{$fileName}{$arquivo['file_ext']}";

          //Upload file to the remote server
          $this->ftp->upload($source, ".".$destino);

          //Close FTP connection
          $this->ftp->close();
          @unlink($source);
        }else{
          $this->session->set_flashdata('error','Problema de conexão com o servidor de documentos.');
          @unlink($source);
          redirect(base_url()."admin/atos/de/editar/".$this->input->post('id'));
        }
```

Após efetuar o envio pelo FTP excluo o arquivo da pasta temporária na hospedagem ou caso teve falha no envio também o excluo.

Processo pode ficar um pouco lento para arquivos maiores de 5mb.